# Error when reading workout route data from health kit in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode, healthkit

In health kit when I try to collect route data from the workout sample I get the error:

Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.healthd.server was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 named com.apple.healthd.server was interrupted, but the message was sent over an additional proxy and therefore this proxy has become invalid.

I have already obtained workout and workout route permissions and I have imported core location and obtained “when in use” location permission. I am using a real iPhone 8 for testing not the simulator.

My code is below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *someDate = [cal dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:(-3) toDate:[NSDate date] 
options:0];

NSDate *startOfDay = [[NSCalendar calendarWithIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian] 
startOfDayForDate:someDate];
NSPredicate *predicate = [HKQuery predicateForSamplesWithStartDate:startOfDay endDate: 
[NSDate date] options:HKQueryOptionStrictStartDate];

HKAnchoredObjectQuery *query = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:[HKWorkoutType 
workoutType] predicate:predicate anchor:nil limit:HKObjectQueryNoLimit 
resultsHandler:^(HKAnchoredObjectQuery * _Nonnull query, NSArray * _Nullable samples, 
NSArray * _Nullable deletedObjects, HKQueryAnchor* anchor,  NSError * _Nullable error) {

                    if (error != nil) {
                        NSLog(@" %@",error);
                    } else {       
                        HKWorkoutRoute * myRoute=samples[0];

                        HKWorkoutRouteQuery * queryroute= [[HKWorkoutRouteQuery alloc]    
                                           initWithRoute:myRoute 
                                           dataHandler:^(HKWorkoutRouteQuery * _Nonnull 
                                            query, NSArray<CLLocation *> * _Nullable 
                                             routeData, BOOL done, NSError *  
                                             _Nullable error) {
                                             NSLog(@" GETTING ROUTE 1 ");

                                   if (error != nil) {
                                       NSLog(@" %@“,error);
                                   } else {                                                                                                              
                                   }

                                   if(done){  
                                       NSLog(@"route data %@",routeData);
                                   }else{

                                   }
                           }];       
                       [self.healthStore executeQuery:queryroute];

        }}];//end anchor

  [self.healthStore executeQuery:query];
```